# How to install Management Studio without Azure Data Studio using Chocolatey

Tags: sql-server, chocolatey

I want to install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) without Azure Data Studio using Chocolatey.

I am trying this, but it does not seem to work:

```
choco install sql-server-management-studio --install-arguments "DoNotInstallAzureDataStudio=1" -Y
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just install it from the downloadable installer?

Comment: For automation @Xedni

Comment: You should explain what "does not seem to work" means - do you get an error message? Does nothing get installed? Does everything get installed? Have you tried formatting your command like the examples in [the documentation](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/sql-server-management-studio) that use `--params "'/param:value'"` instead of what you have above? David Gardiner seems responsive to many of the issues raised, maybe you could ask there?

Comment: In this instance, the OP is trying to pass a option to the native installer, so using `--params` would not work.  `--params` are used when passing options to the package itself, and will not flow through to the native installer.

Comment: It turns out it works as posted, not sure why I was having issues originaly.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [blog post](https://bodnargabor.com/2021/07/10/install-ssms-without-azure-data-studio/) which suggests that you need to install using:

```
SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Passive DoNotInstallAzureDataStudio=1
```

Can you try:

```
choco install sql-server-management-studio --install-arguments="'/Passive DoNotInstallAzureDataStudio=1'" -Y
```